# Form made in Yii returns error, Property is not defined

Tags: php, forms, yii

I have controller EcommerceController.php 
and it looks like this:

```
public function actionLegalisation()
    {
        $model = new Product();

$this->render('legalisation', array('model'=>$model, 'documents'=>$documents, 'countriesIssued'=>$countriesIssued, 'countries'=>$countries, 'flag'=>$flag));
    }
```

And in Legalisation view i have:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'legalisationForm',
    'action' => $this->createUrl($this->id."/".$this->action->id),
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions' => array(
  'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
  'validateOnChange'=>true,
  'validateOnType'=>false,
     ),
)); ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'countriesIssued', $select = array($_POST['countriesIssued'])); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

this code return me an CExeption **Property "Product.countriesIssued" is not defined.**

When i do all of this using Chtml everything is good and a got a dropdown list full with countries name, like this:

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList($form, 'countriesIssued', $select = array($_POST['countriesIssued']),
                  CHtml::listData($countriesIssued, 'code', 'name')); ?>
```

I need the dropdown list to be field with values (countries) Can anyone help me? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This bellow code will give some assistance to overcome the error that you are facing.

**Wring this in your Controller**

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->order = 'country_name ASC';
    $locations = Countries::model()->findAll($criteria);
    $dataAry['countries'] = CHtml::listData($locations, 'id', 'country_name');
    $this->render('index', $dataAry);
```

**Write this in your Form**

```
    echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'attribute', $countries, array('prompt' => 'Select Country'));
    echo $form->error($model, 'attribute');
```

For more information please visit http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/9693-cactiveform-dropdownlist-selectedselected/